# Fluent Validation test not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I have the following class

```
public class PasswordValidator : AbstractValidator<PasswordContainer>
    {
        public PasswordValidator()
        {
            SimpleValidations();
        }

        private void SimpleValidations()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Password.Length).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(8).WithMessage("Password too short.");
            RuleFor(x => x.Password.Length).LessThanOrEqualTo(255).WithMessage("Password too long.");
        }
}
```

`PasswordContainer` looks like this

```
public class PasswordContainer
    {
        public PasswordContainer()
        {
        }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, when I run this and use it for validating an entered password it all works as expected.  But, when I create a unit test it fails

```
[Test]
        public void Validate_WhenPasswordTooShort_ShouldReturnError()
        {
            var subject = fixture.Create<PasswordValidator>();
            subject.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(b => b.Password, new PasswordContainer() { Password = "pass" });
        }
```

This test does not work.  I get an error saying

> "Expected a validation error for property Password"

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably specify the same expression when setting up the rules as you do in your tests. `GreaterThanOrEqualTo` probably works best on numeric properties.

Try this instead:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Password)
.Length(8, 255)
.WithMessage("Password should be between 8 and 255 characters.")
```